# How to develop custom camera app for different manufacters

Tags: android

I'm developing custom camera Application.  I set android manifest file screen mode portrait.   It works fine on HTC and others, but on Samsung mobile, an orientation problem occurs.  How can develop custom camera for all devices..

> Camera module

```
public class Cameramodule extends Activity  {

Camerapriview preview;
FrameLayout cameraframe;
Button b,camswitch;
ImageButton camera_settings,Take_picture;

public static int second_select=0;
 Animation animation;

int orienation;

SensorManager sensorManager;

ImageButton flash,camera_switching;

RelativeLayout second_overlay;
int flag=1;

public static int cam_switch_flag=1;

Button one,two,five,eight,ten,infinity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cameramodule);






    one=(Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    two=(Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    five=(Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    eight=(Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    ten=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
    infinity=(Button) findViewById(R.id.infinity);

    one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            second_select=1;
            second_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    });

    two.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            second_select=2;
            second_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    five.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            second_select=5;
            second_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    eight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            second_select=8;
            second_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    ten.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            second_select=10;
            second_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    infinity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            second_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            second_select=0;//zero means infinity;

        }
    });

    preview=new Camerapriview(this,Cameramodule.this);

    second_overlay=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.second_overlay);
    second_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);


    cameraframe=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mframe);
    camera_settings=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera_settings);
    Take_picture=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.taje_picture);

    camera_switching=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera_switch);


    orienation=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;



    cameraframe.addView(preview);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);


    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
    int height = display.getHeight();





    //create dialog box..





    /*
     * 
     * Camera record setting options
     */


    Take_picture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            preview.camera.takePicture(null, new Rwacallbackhandler(getApplicationContext()), new Photohandler(getApplicationContext()));



        }
    });


    /*
     * Switch the front and back camera...
     */
    camera_switching.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             preview.callswitch(Cameramodule.this);

             if(cam_switch_flag==1)
             {
             cam_switch_flag=2;
             }
             else if (cam_switch_flag==2) {
                 cam_switch_flag=1;

            }



        }
    });

    //create flash option

    camera_settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(flag==1)
            {
            second_overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startAnimationPopOut();

            flag=2;
            }
            else if(flag==2)
            {
                second_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //startAnimationPopOut();
                flag=1;

            }

        }
    });


}



private void startAnimationPopOut() {         


     animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.layout_animation);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {                  
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

   second_overlay.clearAnimation();
   second_overlay.startAnimation(animation);

}
```

}

> Camerapriview

```
public class Camerapriview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public static Activity mactivity;
SurfaceHolder holder;
public Camera camera;
List<String> coloreffect;
public Context mcoContext;
int currentCameraId=Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;


int cameraId=Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

public Camerapriview(Context context, Cameramodule cameramodule) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mcoContext=context;
    mactivity=cameramodule;

    holder=getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);




}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    //setCameraDisplayOrientation(mactivity, cameraId, camera);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    camera.startPreview();





}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    camera=Camera.open(cameraId);

    Camera.Parameters param=camera.getParameters();
    param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    camera.setParameters(param);


    holder.setFixedSize(mactivity.getWindow().getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),mactivity.getWindow().getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());



    try
    {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(this.holder);


    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //preview.this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);



            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();

            camera.release();
            holder = null;
            camera = null;






}



//Set the orientation of the camera.....

    public  void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
             int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) 
    {

        camera.stopPreview();
         android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                 new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
         android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
         int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                 .getRotation();
         int degrees = 0;
         switch (rotation) {
             case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0;
             Toast.makeText(mcoContext,"degree zero", 1000).show();
                                        break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90;

             Toast.makeText(mcoContext,"degree 90", 1000).show();

                                        break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180;
             Toast.makeText(mcoContext,"degree 180", 1000).show();

                                        break;
             case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270;
             Toast.makeText(mcoContext,"degree 270", 1000).show();

                                        break;
         }

         int result;
         if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
             result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
             result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
         } else {  // back-facing
             result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
         }

         camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);


     }

    public void callswitch(Cameramodule cameramodule)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {

        Activity myactivity=cameramodule;

         camera.release();

            //swap the id of the camera to be used
            if(currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
                currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
            }
            else {
                currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
            }
            camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
            //Code snippet for this method from somewhere on android developers, i forget where

            setCameraDisplayOrientation(myactivity, currentCameraId, camera);

            try {
                //this step is critical or preview on new camera will no know where to render to
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            camera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Toast.makeText(mcoContext, e.getMessage().toString(), 1000).show();
        }

    }

    //set the flash modes...

    public void setflash() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(mcoContext, "Inside set", 1000).show();
        Log.i("flash", "My flash");

        Camera.Parameters param=camera.getParameters();

        List<String> flash=param.getSupportedFlashModes();

        if(camera.getParameters().getFlashMode()==Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)
        {
            if(flash.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
                param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

        }

            else
            {
                if(flash.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
                param.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);

            }

        camera.setParameters(param);
        }




    }
```

> I having the orientation problem.I want to set screen always portrait mode.

Comment: what problems are you having? give details and maybe we can help

Comment: I posted the code also.I want set the screenmode in portrait,but samsung mobile not supporting that mode.Help me to find common solution for all android mobiles

Comment: Often times in these cases, _Samsung phones_ are the outliers. Granted they do have a large market share, I'm not too sure if any other manufacturers' phones will display this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some help on the Samsung Android Developer Website, where they overview [Common Issues in Android](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Common-Issues-in-Android). You have a lot of code in there for me to look through, but I saw this section:

> Issue: Preview displays in the wrong orientation.

and thought this page could be of some help to you.

Comment: Did any of the answers here help you?

Answer (score 0):

are you getting an exception, or is it ignoring your setDisplayOrientation() call, or something else?
try makine sure your width/height are supported in portrait.  I once had a simlar problem with setting portrait mode, in you surfaceChanged, try:

```
 final Camera.Parameters parameters = this.mCamera.getParameters();
 List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(); 
 Camera.Size cs = previewSizes.get(0);

 mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
 parameters.setPreviewSize(cs.width,cs.height);
 this.mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

 this.mCamera.startPreview();
```

Comment: Still having the problem in samsung mobile.How can get common solution for all mobiles